# EF how to filter data by date

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I' using EF 4, I have a property `DateTimeStart` in my entities with datein this format `16/08/2012 08:14:40`,  I would like query with EF and find all the entities `within the date  16/08/2012 only`. Using this code below code I receive this error

```
The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

my code

```
 DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DateTime dateNow = dateTimeNow.Date;
        return db.EventCustoms.Where(x => x.DataTimeStart.Date <= dateNow)
            .Select(y => new { y.EventId, y.EventTitle, y.DataTimeStart });
```

Comment: What datatype is the DataTimeStart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime dateTomorrow = dateTimeNow.Date.AddDays(1);
return db.EventCustoms.Where(x => x.DataTimeStart < dateTomorrow) 
            .Select(y => new { y.EventId, y.EventTitle, y.DataTimeStart });
```

**[Edit]** @GibboK, To elaborate a bit:

Entity Framework cannot translate the [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property on your DateTime object at the database side.

Your options are:

(1) (As above) To rethink your query and try for a solution that does not require a function call at the database side for each row in your table.... which is good for query performance too

(2) or if that isn't possible, you can make use of the [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412643) class, which exposes methods (such as [TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596)) that **can** be translated by EF into the appropriate native function for the underlying data source.

e.g.

```
return db.EventCustoms
    .Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DataTimeStart) <= dateNow)
```

Comment: While implementing this answer today, I discovered that `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityFunctions` is deprecated and should be replaced by `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions`.  The same TruncateTime() method exists in the new namespace/class, so simply changing `EntityFunctions` to `DbFunctions` and adding the correct using statement should work well for future users of this answer.

Comment: But be aware, in what SQL statement this will be translated. It is something like `((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Filter1].[DateTimeStart], 102), 102)) <= '2017-01-13 00:00:00'`- so I think I will go with the `dateTomorrow` version, as this will not need any conversion in the DB on row level.

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DateTime dateNow = dateTimeNow.Date;
        return db.EventCustoms.Where(
             x => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(x.DataTimeStart, dateNow) >= 0)
            .Select(y => new { y.EventId, y.EventTitle, y.DataTimeStart });
```

Comment: hi Amiram Korach, unfortunately does not work, could you please have a look and let me know? many thanks for your time

Comment: Sorry my mistake. It should be ">=". This method will give you positive number if the first value is smaller than the second.

Answer (score 1):

In EF 6 :

```
using System.Data.Entity;
...
db.EventCustoms.Where(x => 
 DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DataTimeStart) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(dateNow))
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not a proper solution but it will help you

```
DateTime startOfDay = new DateTime(invoiceDate.Value.Year, invoiceDate.Value.Month, invoiceDate.Value.Day, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime endOfDay = new DateTime(invoiceDate.Value.Year, invoiceDate.Value.Month, invoiceDate.Value.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999);
predicate.And(x => x.InvoiceDate >= startOfDay && x.InvoiceDate<= endOfDay);
```